# web2py grid with vertical scroll bar and fixed header

Tags: grid, web2py, scrollable

How to make web2py2.3.2 grid with vertical scroll bar and fixed header?
Applied css to make it vertically scrollable as below -

```
.web2py_grid > .table {
  height: 504px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.web2py_grid > .table > div > table > thead {
position: fixed;
}
```

When I am applying - position: fixed; property for the "thead". Its giving me fixed header but in that case its width doesn't get adjust with the contents below.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Hee guys I found out one fantastic solution here- http://www.fixedheadertable.com/